# git API returning 401 unauthorized error when doing axios call but curl returns 200

Tags: javascript, git, curl, axios

axios call to git API returns 401, but curling the same URL with the same headers returns 200 with the correct data, anybody know why?

### Axios call returns 401

```
let headers = {
    "Authorization": "token abc",
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

    await axios.get("SOME_GIT_API_URL", headers)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data)

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

### Curl returns 200

```
curl --location --request GET "SOME_GIT_API_URL" --header 'Authorization: token abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

On axios, header key must be inside the object. Your header variable not included that 'header' as key. Example :

```
// header inside an object
const headerObject = {
  header: {
    "Authorization": "token abc",
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}

await axios.get("SOME_GIT_API_URL", headerObject)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.data)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
  })
```